# How to url rewrite /index_lang.php to /lang/index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

my question is pretty simple but I'm new to .htaccess and haven't seen an example over internet that I could understand and apply...

I have two indexes: `index.php` and `index_fr.php`.

I would like that `index_fr.php` to be `fr/index.php` and if possible redirect browser with french language to the `fr/index.php` and all other to `index.php`.

Also, I wonder what will happen when I try to access `img/picture.jpg` from the `fr/` root. Will it look into `fr/img/picture.jpg` (and in this case image will be broken) ?

Thanks to you guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (fr) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /fr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?fr/index\.php$ /index_fr.php [L]
```

This will internally rewrite incoming requests to `/fr/index.php` to `/index_fr.php` without touching any request whose path component does *not* match that leading two letter pattern (so for example `/img/...` which has three letters in front).

For that to work the http servers rewrite module has to be enabled, also the interpretation of dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess`) has to be enabled and the file holding that rule has to be located in the `DocumentRoot` of that http host.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).